# Android - Webview Element onClick event is not triggering?

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-webview, onclicklistener

In a Webview, I am loading a local index.html file and adding HTML content using javaScript to Webview from remote.
I want to perfrom some tasks like showing tooltip, alert box extra when users click on element contained by Webview. 
P.S It sounds like it has pretty straight forward solution. But I am able to do so ! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Adding a WebView to Your Application**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

In JAVA load URL

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

Add INTERNET Permission

```
<manifest ... >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
...
```

Enable `javascript` in webview

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Make Interface

```
public class WebAppInterface {
Context mContext;

/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

/** Show a toast from the web page */
@JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

You can bind this class to the JavaScript that runs in your WebView with addJavascriptInterface() and name the interface Android. For example:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "android");
```

In your HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helped you

Source https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#AddingWebView

Comment: I do not need an interface as tooltip and alert are shown in HTML not in Andorid native.

Answer (score 1):

shouldOverrideUrlLoading

ex.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url!= && url.endWith("your_url.html")) {

        //your tootip, alertIDialog, etc.

        // return true to report that we have intercepted the event
        return true;
      }
      return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)